# Function to decode a series of numbers

Tags: math, sequences

I have a set of numbers that goes 99 170 270 410 606 880 1265.  When a function that takes the difference of item n and n+1 to get n+2 it doesnt seem accurate as there common difference seems to be another set of numbers itself.  Can anyone predict the next 50 numbers or suggest an improvement to my algorithm?

Comment: Suppose I said the next 50 numbers were 0,1,2,3,...49. How would you know if the answer is right or wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try quotient instead of difference, corresponding to an exponential relation:  X[n+2] = X[n+1] * (X[n+1] / X[n]).   Not perfect either, but a considerable improvement.

Comment: How is it a considerable improvement??

Comment: Right, I should state my assumptions.  I assumed this is about real numbers, and the goal is to provide an extrapolation scheme that predicts the subsequent numbers as closely as possible.

Comment: But are we sure its going to be an infinite sequence or will it converge??

Answer (score 0):

Try fitting it to a geometric sequence.
Written in c++

```
int a = 99;
double r = (double)99/170;

for (int i = 0; i < 56; i++)
  {
    cout << a*(pow(r,i) << endl;
  }
```